# Как максимально быстро и удобно поставить брейкпоинт на результат выражения в IDE Delphi?

Tags: delphi, ide

В работе часто встречается ситуация, когда надо максимально быстро и удобно поставить брейкпоинт в коде по какому-то условию. К примеру программа вылетает с ошибкой "Integer Overflow" на строке:

```
Result := a + b + c - d[n] - e[k] - f; // Result типа Cardinal
```

, при возникновении исключения жмем Break и в отладчике мы оказываемся на паузе и можем пройтись по Call Stack и посмотреть что пошло не так, но вот выполнить код, к примеру выражение выше, уже не можем, т.к. локальные переменные и Self "ушли".

Ошибка 100% воспроизводима, так что напрашивается поставить брейкпоинт прямо перед строкой с ошибкой и рестартовать прогу, чтобы в отладчике иметь доступ ко всем переменным и выполнению выражений.

Сейчас я копирую выражение в IF и делаю вот так:

```
if a + b + c - d[n] - e[k] - f < 0 then 
  Sleep(0); // И на эту строку ставлю брейкпоинт F5
```

Вопрос - как в IDE поставить брейкпоинт на результат какого-то выражения быстрее / удобнее / минимальным количеством действий? *В идеале - только с клавиатуры, выделить часть выражения нажать что-то, добавить условие и всё.*

Comment: Для этих целей в IDE предусмотрены условия для брейкпоинтов. https://bit.ly/2myztvf https://bit.ly/2O63Wxp

Comment: @kot-da-vinci Да, но я не знаю как ими удобно пользоваться, какие есть шоткаты на эти действия, к примеру? Я встречал только F5 и Shift+F5 для постановки и временного отключения брейкпоинта. P.S. Пожалуйста не пользуйтесь сокращалками ссылок - они не всегда работают и не дают понять куда ведет ссылка.

Comment: Можно с помощью GExperts(IDE menu shortcuts) назначить хоткей на `Source Breakpoint...`. И тогда последовательность будет такая... 1) Копирование нужного выражения(через Ctrl+C) 2) Вызов окна брэкпоинта(через настроенный хоткей) 3) Вставка в поле условия скопированного ранее выражения. Удобней без создания плагина наверно не получится.

Comment: ... только встроенные брекпоинты по условию тормозят сильно, так что проще наверное делать как сейчас - через if.